# MySQL cumulative sum gives wrong result

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

Here is the sample of my [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90e20/1) with some sample data-

The strange things happens while making cumulative sum of difference between columns gorivo.PovratKM and gorivo.PolazakKM and same for gorivo.UkupnoGorivo.

The cumulative sums are in column **SumUkKM** for difference between *gorivo.PovratKM* and *gorivo.PolazakKM* and for cumulative sum for *gorivo.UkupnoGorivo* is column **SumGorivo**.

The output should be something like:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+  
| Polazak KM  | Povratal KM| Prijedeno KM|  SumUkKM   |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+  
| 814990      | 816220     |      1230   |    1230    |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 816220      | 817096     |      876    |    2106    |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 817096      | 817124     |      28     |    2134    |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 817124      | 818426     |      1302   |    3436    |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

What I'm doing wrong in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql allows to declare variables in the sql sentence, `(select @SumUkGorivo := 0, @SumUkKM := 0) x` the CROSS JOIN allows to calculate its value for each row of the other table.

Using variables, you can, for example set reset points or partitions on the same way than `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY` is used by other dmbs like SQL or Postgres.

```
SELECT 
   y.`PolazakKM`, y.`PovratakKM`,
   @SumUkGorivo := @SumUkGorivo + `UkupnoGorivo` as SumUkGorivo,
   @SumUkKM := @SumUkKM + (y.`PovratakKM` - y.`PolazakKM`) as SumUkKM
FROM 
    (select @SumUkGorivo := 0, @SumUkKM := 0) x,
    (select gorivo.`PolazakKM`, gorivo.`PovratakKM`, gorivo.`UkupnoGorivo`
     from gorivo WHERE gorivo.`IDVozilo` = 131
     order by `DatumT`) y
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't have idea that can be solved on this way.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Comment: @McNets It is interesting to do loop in SQL. Can you please break down the behaviour of this query? Also can you please explain the behaviour when `(select @SumUkGorivo := 0, @SumUkKM := 0) x,` is commented out? - `@SumUkkm` starts with 9854 (which is the final sum of the differences) instead of 0. So it goes like this 11084 (9854+1230), 11960(9854+1230+876) ... Why?

Comment: I suppose it is because I've added `order by DatumT`. Unfortunately I've deleted the rextester.com used to get the solution. Try by deleting the order sentence and it will begin at 0.